# How to keep items updated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

Is sending requests to server every second, the best way to keep list of items updated for all users? For example, if one user adds or deletes an item, all other users see the changes without refreshing page.

Comment: no, sending requests to the server every second, is not the best way. you should look into websockets and broadcast an event like an item is added, or item is deleted to clients which care, like if a client is viewing said list/page, then they can react like reload the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all! That would be very network-consuming! You should either look for storage options with embedded listeners for changes like Firebase, or opt for some kind of publish-subscribe architecture where you notify the interested parts to pull data.